# prevent current user from reading his own file

Tags: permissions, backup, chown

Edit: The short question is: How do I give away access to files that my (non-priviledged) user currently owns. I would like to be unable to get access to them in any way. Please see the rest of the post for a more detailed description.

---

For some backups, I would like to copy files to a remote location. I would like these files to be secure, even in the case the local machine is compromised.

Initially, my plan was to `chown` the remote files to root as soon as they were written. This would not allow access from the local machine anymore, but in case of disaster would allow me to recover from the remote machine (assuming that one is not breached of course). It turns out however that `chown`ing to another user is not allowed in Linux for security reasons. Is there another method to give away access to a file you currently own?

The remote machine is a raspberry pi running Raspbian Stretch and the local machine is running FreeNAS 11.0-U4. The local machine can `ssh` to the remote machine as a non-privileged user. I would like permissions of this user on the remote machine as limited as possible.

Comment: Please read our FAQ; this question can potentially be off-topic on 2 or 3 counts.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: could you point out what the violation is specifically and where the question would be better asked? The topic list includes "Using or administering a *nix desktop or server" and "Shell scripting", which both feel like they include this question.

Comment: "Unclear what you are asking", "too broad", "Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications).". You always do backups that the owner of the original files cannot touch.

Comment: To answer the first two: I think this is a very specific question, but it might not be clear enough. I try to update my question to be more clear. Regarding the "request for learning materials (...)": I am looking for a way of solving this problem, so I guess you could qualify this as a how-to, but I fail to see how this is different than any question being asked. I haven't bee able to find the answer with a Google search or a search on SE if that's what you're afraid of.

Comment: Are you using `scp` to copy the files to the remote system? You can configure the remote system to run a custom version of ssh/scp for this user that will copy the files and then chown them to give them away  (using sudo).

Comment: I am using `rsync`, but you are suggesting to give the user sudo permissions for `chown`?

Comment: That would be an egregious abuse of the "Requests for learning materials" close criterion, ironically when https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/ is right there on the Hot Meta Posts lists at the side of this page.

Comment: It should be possible to write a shell script that can be run with sudo. It can move the files to a root-owned unreadable directory and then, optionally, chmod and chown them so they're not writable.

Comment: How about encrypting the files?

Comment: Unclear. (1) What machines do you have `sudo` privileges on?  If you have them on the remote machine, what’s the problem with doing `sudo chown`?  (2) What do you mean by “I would like these files to be secure”?  Are you concerned that malware might infect your local machine and read your (remote) backup files?  Why is that a concern — aren’t the *current* files on the local machine, owned by you, with normal access?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Are you concerned that malware might infect your local machine and tamper with your (remote) backup files? Then why do you say “prevent current user from reading his own file”? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

On a multi-user system with disk quotas, allowing unprivileged users to give away files to other users would allow the users to abuse each other's disk quotas.

It would be trivial for User A to create a directory that is accessible only by User A, then fill it with large files and give them all away to User B. Now User B's disk quota is exhausted by files that cannot be accessed by User B.

The ability of users to give away files (the SysV semantics for chown()) used to cause several kinds of security issues, and is now regarded in literature as broken behavior. For example, if you accidentally allow other users to write into your home directory, another user on the same system might want to give you some files/directories. Like `<your_homedir>/.ssh/authorized_keys` for example. Or `<your_homedir>/.rhosts` in the bad old days. Each of those could be used to allow access to your account, and you'd have difficult time proving it wasn't you.

On a Linux system, you might use `sudo` to allow the setting of the "immutable" attribute for the files, but not the command to clear it. This would be the example configuration line for `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Octaviour  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chattr -R +i /your/backup/directory
```

You could then run `sudo chattr -R +i /your/backup/directory` but not the corresponding `chattr -R -i` command using your regular user account. The immutable bit can normally be set or cleared by root only.

(If Linux Capabilities are in use, a process with the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability could do it. But it would be highly unusual for normal users to have that, and the use of capabilities themselves is pretty uncommon.)